# Why must I cast int to bool before checking "is True"?

Tags: python, django

In my url.py file in Django, I have the following line:

```
if bool(settings.DEBUG) is True:
```

This works well because settings.DEBUG == 1 therefore it equals True after the bool() function. However, I needed to add the bool() to make it work. The original line was not working and the original line was:

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
```

This always evaluates to False, even when settings.DEBUG == 1.

Why is the value 1 evaluating to False when I do not cast it explicitly to bool?

In other words, why doesn't "1 is True" evaluate true?

Note that I am using python 3 in case that matters to the answer.

Comment: `1` and `True` are two distinct objects (one `int` and one `bool`).  They are certainly not the *same* object, which is all that `is` checks for - it knows nothing about any concept of equality or equivalence of different objects.  Note that you don't actually need any sort of comparison here - the idiomatic way to write this test is `if settings.DEBUG:`, the conversion to boolean is implicit.

Comment: Small addition to @jasonharper comment. The difference between equality and identity is the key. True is not 1 but True equals 1.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, this can be confusing as of course, the value of '1' should equal true right? However what if this int value equals '99' should this be true also?

By comparing an int with a Boolean value within the python compiler it is like comparing apples with oranges which isn't possible therefore defaulting to 'false'.

By wrapping your int value in a bool(function) you are declaring to the python compiler treat this int value as a boolean (0 == False, 1 == True) therefore it works as you intended.

Hope this helps :)